# Spring-mvc setup issue

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven, spring-mvc

I am trying to do the basic Maven-Spring MVC setup in STS, but somehow I am not able to remove the red underline mark. I have attached a screenshot and also POM.xml file as reference. I don't think I have missed anything because I have included spring-wewbmvc, spring-context and log4j as dependency and that should work.

First I created dynamic web project into STS and then converted into Maven Project.

Please find below screenshot of my directory and AppInitializer class.I just want to get compile and produce out output HelloWorld in the console. That's it!

[image: Spring MVC Setup]

[image: Spring dependency]

POM.XML

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.gami.mvc</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-mvc-foundation</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.takari.m2e.workspace/org.eclipse.m2e.workspace.cli -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.takari.m2e.workspace</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.m2e.workspace.cli</artifactId>
    <version>0.4.0</version>
</dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: I would better suggest to use Spring Boot if you are just starting of. It would skip all these set up things and directly get you up and running .You would be able to  focus more on the core concepts and then come back and spend time on these wiring details .

Comment: I totally agree, I was tryng to see how spring got evolved, I was under the impression for lng time that Spring boot is one type of framework like Spring MVC but actually to remove out setup things and make the life of developers a little easy, Spring came out with fast approach that's Spring boot.

Answer (score 0):

Oh okay, sorry I got it..

added 2 more dependency into POM.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

and it worked.. surprisingly, I don't knw why .. I thought in spring-context and spring-webmvc would be good enough and it should cover servlet dependency too